# Dynamic numeric arrays

Tags: c, dynamic, numeric, dynamic-arrays

How do this in C? Fill the matrix with random numbers.
Mapping the upper half of the matrix to the lower half
mirror symmetrically along the horizontal axis.

I made a function to output a multidimensional array and generate a random number. I am stuck on the next step: I don't know how to map the top half of the matrix to the bottom half mirror symmetrically along the horizontal axis.

```
const int m = 3, n = 4;
void InputMatrix(int x[m][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter [%d][%d]:", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);
        }
}
void PrintMatrix(int x[m][n])
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", x[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void FillMatrix(int x[m][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            x[i][j] = rand() % 100 - 50;
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Note that you said you have a function that 'outputs' an array, however you can't return arrays from functions.

Comment: I don't know how to map the top half of the matrix to the bottom half 
mirror symmetrically about the horizontal axis.

Comment: If `x[i][j]` is in the top half of the matrix, `x[m-1-i][j]` is at the mirrored position.

Comment: I tried it, it works, thanksI tried it, it works, thanks